# __init__ incorrect number of parameters

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I'm pretty sure I'm passing in the correct number of parameters, but for some reason, it states that I'm missing 1 positional argument('figure'), but I am passing in figure; hence my confusion. Here's my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QPushButton,QVBoxLayout
import sys

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
```

The last line errors out. What am I doing wrong?

```
File "C:\Users\...\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt4agg.py", line 76, in __init__
FigureCanvasQT.__init__(self, figure)
File "C:\Users\...\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt4.py", line 71, in __init__
QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'figure'
```

Comment: please post the full traceback. Which constructor has the issue? Is it `FigureCanvas`?

Comment: The linked question includes a stack trace that shows the error is in backend_qt4.py. Is that the case here? You really need to post stack traces with questions like this so we can see what is happening.

Comment: Hi I edited the question, sorry.

Comment: oh yeah the link does answer it I'm an idiot. Thanks guys.